# How do I give one method invoked in a block the ability to see variables set in the context of the calling function?

Tags: ruby

I have a module that defines a method, `logged`, which will add a prefix to the result of a different method, `say`:

```
module M
  def logged(&block)
    str = "logged: "
    block.call
  end

  def say(value)
    puts str + value
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to use `M` inside the body of a `class` block, like so:

```
class C
  extend M

  logged {
    say "one"
    say "two"
  }
end
```

and get:

```
# => "logged: one"
# => "logged: two"
```

Essentially, I want `say` to be able to access values in `logged` that are only in `logged`'s calling context. So, I'd prefer to avoid instance variables, global variables, et cetera.

What's the right way to pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this :-

```
module M
  def logged(&block)
    str = "logged: "
    block.call(str)
  end

  def say(str, value)
    puts str + value
  end
end

class C
  extend M

  logged { |s|
    say s, "one"
    say s, "two"
  }
end
```

Comment: Nice one, Arup.  It's perhaps worth mentioning that since `logged` is invoked on the class, it and `say` must be class methods, which is why you used `extend`.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was angling for, because I was hoping I could get `str` by virtue of it being present at the call site -- it's not very dry to do it this way if you had a lot of `say` methods. But I guess that doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnFeminella It will work, but in that case, you need to use block and need to create method dynamically, which is sometimes considered as *bad* practices... But I think  your code, with my little police is perfect. Don't use *closure* things, if you really need it.